# Eclipse C++, Compiling via cmd works, compilling in eclipse does not

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, cmdline-args

I have a TCP Client program (TCPClient.cpp) using winsock library. An *.exe is generated successfully if I use command line with the following call:

```
g++ TCPClient.cpp -o TCPClient.exe -lws2_32
```

When I try to compile and link the same script within Eclipse/C++ using MinGW I seem to get the *.o file generated but I get an error when generating the *.exe.
Thus, the error is generated if Ecplise/C++ does the following (linker call):

```
g++ -o TCPClient.exe TCPClient.o -lws2_32
```

I get multiple errors:

> enter C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
> ./src/TCPClient.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x2a0): multiple definition of
> _mingw32_init_mainargs
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x2a0): first defined here
> C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
> ./src/TCPClient.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x2e0): multiple definition of
> `mainCRTStartup' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x2e0): first defined here C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84. ./src/TCPClient.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x300): multiple definition of`     WinMainCRTStartup'
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x300): first defined here
> C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
> ./src/TCPClient.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x320): multiple definition of `atexit' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x320): first defined here C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84. ./src/TCPClient.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x330): multiple definition of` _onexit'
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x330): first defined here
> C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
> ./src/TCPClient.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x340): multiple definition of
> `__gcc_register_frame'
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x0): first
> defined here
> C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.here

The following is interesting:
I get the same errors if I use the cmd-line and first generate a .o file and then try to generate a *.exe. Both of the following calls in cmd-line result in the error from above:

```
g++ TCPClient.o -o TCPClient.exe -lws2_32

g++ TCPClient.o -o TCPClient.exe
```

This means: If in cmd-line I only specify that I want to generate (a *.exe from my *.cpp) everything works fine. But - as a user - doing those two steps separately does not work.

Cmd-Line g++ call seems to "know" what to do here. As a user I never see the *.o file when directly generating a *.exe. But I think it must be generated anyway? Am I wrong? Why does cmd-line without further specification know how to deal with the .o file? ... Is it possible to find out from any source what a call to "g++" does when called via command line? Of course I want the same settings integrated in eclipse/c++.

Comment: Looks like either a borked compiler installation, or more than one installation conflicting with one another. Uninstall all copies MinGW and replace them with [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075).

Comment: I agree with @HolyBlackCat In fact you probably have a mix of a very old MinGW and cygwin. Get MSYS2 and use `pacman` to get a proper MinGW-w64 compiler suite, or if you don't intend to use MSYS2 you can also get a standalone MinGW-w64 compiler suite for Windows from https://winlibs.com/

Answer (score 0):

> g++ TCPClient.cpp -o TCPClient.exe -lws2_32

You can get that error if you do -O (capital letter, not zero) instead of -o for the exe file.